Stuck at GRUB prompt after fresh Slackware install: Disk Not Found, need kernel loading help
I have just completed a new install of the latest slackware which went surprisingly well. Everything completed no errors.
I was prompted to reboot. But have now a problem I have no idea how to solve.
I simply have a grub prompt and I haven't a clue how to proceed. I tried "boot" but prompted that I needed to load the kernel first ??? Typed some info on I read from other similar posts but I keep getting disk hd0 not found.
I would bet much appreciate some concise help 
My partition table is as follows.
/dev/sda1 300mb efi system
/dev/sda2  30gb Linux root
/dev/sda3  700gb Linux home
/dev/sda4   32gb  Linux swap 
/dev/sda5   70gb  Linux /use

This was done in cfdisk.
What have I done wrong ?

First step in troubleshooting this: Open UEFI settings > Boot menu and check if there are other option in OS selection (or similar) and then try them. You may have more than one entry if you made several attempt at installing, only the last one, if any, works. Make sure to [edit] your question accordingly.

I don't know where the UEFI settings are out how to find them. This is a iMac late 2012 and I just hold alt key to get to boot options, which there is only one, which then presents me with three grub prompt. After reading another post I've found that the root file system, /boot /dev /proc /run....... Is on (hd1,2)

At grub prompt I've set root to the above. But I have no ideas how to find the correct kernel name, tab doesn't auto complete.
